# How can I exclude a range of datetimes from a dateutil rruleset?

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil, rrule

I have an `rruleset()` that contains a base rrule:

```py
rset = rruleset()
rset.rrule(rrule(SECONDLY, dtstart=start_date, interval=duration, until=end_date))
```

I would like to exclude a range of datetimes from this set.

For example: I want to exclude any occurrences of Mondays from 3:00pm to 9:00pm, is this possible with the rrule implementation or will I need to create a function to accomplish this?

Comment: Looks like you could use `rset.exdate()` according to [this guide](https://www.nylas.com/blog/calendar-events-rrules/) (see section titled "Cancellations"), but since you're using a `SECONDLY` recurrence rule, it would take a lot of exclusion date rules, so it may not be practical.